# about autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false

Tags: hibernate

what is `"autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false"` and why we write it in application.properties ?

I have MySql installed on my machine and when i removed that line it wont create any tables in my database.

```
    # Database
    db.driver: com.mysql.jdbc.Driver
    db.url: jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/test? 
    autoReconnect=true&useSSL=false
    db.username: root
    db.password: root
```

I expect that the all the tables are to be created in database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

These are properties of the MySQL JDBC Driver.

> **autoReconnect**
>
> Should the driver try to re-establish stale and/or dead connections?
>   If enabled the driver will throw an exception for a queries issued on
>   a stale or dead connection, which belong to the current transaction,
>   but will attempt reconnect before the next query issued on the
>   connection in a new transaction. The use of this feature is not
>   recommended, because it has side effects related to session state and
>   data consistency when applications don't handle SQLExceptions
>   properly, and is only designed to be used when you are unable to
>   configure your application to handle SQLExceptions resulting from dead
>   and stale connections properly. Alternatively, as a last option,
>   investigate setting the MySQL server variable "wait_timeout" to a high
>   value, rather than the default of 8 hours.
>
> Default: false
>
> Since version: 1.1
>
> **useSSL**
>
> Use SSL when communicating with the server (true/false), default is
>   'true' when connecting to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ or 5.7.6+, otherwise
>   default is 'false'
>
> Default: false
>
> Since version: 3.0.2
>
> Use SSL when communicating with the server (true/false), default is
>   'true' when connecting to MySQL 5.5.45+, 5.6.26+ or 5.7.6+, otherwise
>   default is 'false'
>
> Default: false
>
> Since version: 3.0.2

You can find all properties in the Driver manual:

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-j/5.1/en/connector-j-reference-configuration-properties.html